# MySQL: create new table using same table twice

Tags: mysql, data-structures

I want to use 1 table to create a new table using 2 sets of queries.

To test out the code: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02e3ff/5

## Reference table:

[image]

## Desired table:

[image]

They share the same order_id. 
type = A, updated_at = pDate 
type = B, updated_at = dDate

### Query 1:

```
select t.order_id, t.updated_at as pDate, weekday(t.updated_at) from transactions t 
where t.type = 'A' group by t.order_id
```

### Query 2:

```
select t.order_id, max(t.updated_at) as dDate, weekday(max(t.updated_at)) from transactions t 
where t.type= 'B'
group by t.order_id;
```

For type = A, I want to get the earliest *updated_at* date, while for type = B, I want to get the latest *updated_at* date.

Currently, I tried union but they give me 2 rows instead of the desired table.

How do I join or union these 2 queries to get the desired table?

Alternatively, is there a better method to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT order_id, min(pDate) pDate, max(dDate) dDate FROM(
    SELECT
      order_id,
      if(type='A',updated_at,null) pDate,
      if(type='B',updated_at,null) dDate
    FROM transactions
) as d
GROUP BY order_id
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9415df/1)

Comment: I receive error 1248, I think it doesn't work if there're other order_id?

Comment: Try to add alias to subquery

Comment: I add the fiddle to answer

Comment: @vp_arth, amaksr, Thank you!